# What's the meaning of the suffix "nimity"?

Tags: meaning, suffixes, morphology

I have been researching online for the suffix *nimity* in the English words *equanimity* and *unanimity* but with no clear results.

I have found the suffix *ity* but couldn't find the whole suffix *nimity*.

Can you please explain the meaning of *nimity* in such words, and if this is not a suffix can you explain why and which is the suffix in this cases?

Comment: There is no suffix "nimity". The words divide as "equ-anim-ity" and  "un-anim-ity": "equ-" as in "equal" or "equilibrium," "anim" as in "animate" or "animal",  "un-" as in "unity" or "unique".

Comment: All of this especially etymological info about the false parsing is true, but it's *also* true that English has a propensity for stress-foot parsing in morphology. See for example -holic  constructions.

Answer (score 3):

**Synchronically**, unanimity has one suffix, -ity:

unanimous - unanimity

equanimous - equanimity

**Diachronically**, it goes back to the Latin noun, *[animus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/animus#Latin)* 'mind' and suffix '[tas](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-tas#Latin).'

Answer (score 2):

The suffix you need to look at is ***[-ity](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-ity)*** . In [equanimity](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/equanimity), -ity is the suffix;   ***-nimity*** is not a suffix.

> suffix  ***forming abstract nouns from adjectives, meaning "condition or quality of being ______,"***  from Middle English -ite, from Old French -ité and directly from Latin -itatem (nominative -itas), suffix denoting state or condition, composed of connective -i- + -tas (see -ty (2)).
>
> - ***Roughly, the word in -ity usually means the quality of being what the adjective describes, or concretely an instance of the quality, or collectively all the instances; & the word in -ism means the disposition, or collectively all those who feel it. [Fowler]***

(Etymonline)